# Linq query in VB.net to group several columns

Tags: vb.net, linq

Ok i have the following table

```
Dt.Columns.Add("A1")
Dt.Columns.Add("A2")
Dt.Columns.Add("A3")
Dt.Columns.Add("A4")
Dt.Rows.Add("A", "1", "11", "111")
Dt.Rows.Add("B", "1", "11", "111")
Dt.Rows.Add("C", "1", "12", "121")
Dt.Rows.Add("D", "1", "12")
Dt.Rows.Add("E", "2", "21", "211")
Dt.Rows.Add("F", "2", "21")
Dt.Rows.Add("G", "3")
Dt.Rows.Add("H", "3")
Dt.Rows.Add("I", "3", "31")
```

And i have the following Linq query

```
    Dim Query = From Row In Dt.AsEnumerable()
                Group Key = Row(1), Key2 = Row(2), Key3 = Row(3)
                By Key = Row(1)
                Into Test = Group
```

Which gives me the following result

```
    "1", "11", "111"
    "1", "11", "111"
    "1", "12", "121"
    "1", "12"
```

But i want the query to give me this

```
"1", "11", "111"
"1", "12", "121"
"1", "12", null
"2", "21", "211"
"2", "21", null
"3", null, null
"3", "31", null
```

In plain words i want the query to group by the last 3 columns and output the grouping of those. In Sql it would be something like:

```
Select A2,A3,A4
From Dt
Group by A2,A3,A4
```

I have been fighting with the Linq for a couple of hours but to no avail i manage to get what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim Query = From Row In Dt.Rows
            Group Key = Row(1), Key2 = Row(2), Key3 = Row(3)
            By Key = Row(1), Key2 = Row(2)
            Into Test = Group
```

**UPDATE**

Thinking about it you will probably need

```
By Key = Row(1), Key2 = Row(2), Key3 = Row(3)
```

Comment: Yeah i think that did the trick, now i need to convert it into a Data Table, will update.

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly, btw can you Explain it a bit? I know that From work a bit like "For each XXX in YYY" but the rest is still pretty much "Magic" from my point of view.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, I just took your code and played with it. At first I was getting an error at Dt.AsEnumerable() so changed to Dt.Rows. Next I just though we need to sort by more than one column so added By Key = Row(1), Row(2) and got an error so tried By Key = Row(1), Key2 = Row(2) . Once I got that working I looked at the results and saw we needed to add the third key. Like you say magic :)